# Setting default value in QGIS field using QgsEditorWidgetSetup in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, values, default, default-value

There are many questions like this but either they propose to implement a new method to update values or describe how to set default values for fields in GUI.

I'm writing a QgsProcessingAlgorithm and need to set default values when modifying fields using the QgsEditorWidgetSetup either for 'KeyValue' if the fieldtype is hstore or 'TextEdit' if it's some kind of String-field. Here's what I've tried (for 'TextEdit' because it's simpler):

```
sourceLayer.setEditorWidgetSetup(index, QgsEditorWidgetSetup('TextEdit', 
{
   'DefaultValue': 'DefValue',
   'Defaults': 'DefValue',
   'Default': 'DefValue',
   'IsMultiline': 'True',
   'UseHtml': 'False'
}
```

The properties 'IsMultiline' and 'UseHtml' work flawlessly but none of the defaults is accepted.

A often proposed approach is to use the Python console to get the QgsEditorWidgetSetup config of a field configured via GUI. This is done by the following code:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
layer.fields().names()
idx = layer.fields().indexFromName('text')
field = layer.fields()[idx]
field.editorWidgetSetup().config()
```

Unfortunately the output is just:
`{'IsMultiline': False, 'UseHtml': False}`
Although of course the default value I configured is working fine when I add new features through the attribute table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a layer's field default value with this following code, by using the `QgsVectorLayer`'s [`setDefaultValueDefinition`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html?highlight=qgsvectorlayer#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.setDefaultValueDefinition) method :

```py
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
my_field = layer.fields().names()[1]  # second field
idx = layer.fields().indexFromName(my_field)
default_value = QgsDefaultValue()
default_value.setExpression("'This is the DefaultValue'")
layer.setDefaultValueDefinition(idx, default_value)
```

Comment: Thanks so much J :-)
However, from the PyQGIS API perspective this isn't very straightforward. Furthermore, there isn't a getDefaultValueDefinition, is there?

Comment: You have `field.defaultValueDefinition()` or `layer.defaultValueDefinition(idx)`.

Comment: Thanks :-) However, a set-method but no get-method isn't very straightforward again.

Comment: @Sickboy: that is how Qt is designed in general, take a look here setter `setCurrentIndex`, getter `currentIndex` : https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcombobox.html#currentIndex-prop.

Comment: @Sickboy: if my answer is valid and answers your question, don't forget to accept it.

Comment: @J yeah, of course, no worries, but I only get around working on my project at the weekends. What realy confused me were the double quotes when setting a map to a KeyValue setup. But I woprked it out (ok, you stated it as well, but unfortnuately I thought that this applies to Strings only). Anyway, thanks so much for your help! :-)